# Using string as array indices in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I'm handling large numerical arrays in python through a GUI.
I'd like to expose the slicing capabilities to a textbox in a GUI, so I can easily choose part of the array that should be used for the calculation at hand.

Simple example of what I'd like to do:

```
arr = array([0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])

a = "2:4" # example string from GUI Textbox
b = "[3, 4, 5]" # example string from GUI Textbox


print arr[a] # not valid code -> what should be written here to make it work?
print arr[b] # not valid code -> what should be written here to make it work?
```

should output:

```
[20, 30]
[30, 40, 50]
```

I found out about the slice function, but I'd need to parse my string manually and create a slice. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: is this expected to handle only 1d arrays?

Comment: No, arbitrary dimension (up to fifth at this point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe since you are only expecting a very limited character set it is acceptable using `eval` this once:

```
if not all(c in "1234567890-[],: " for c in b): # maybe also limit the length of b?
    # tell user you couldn't parse and exit this branch
slice_ = eval(f'np.s_[{b}]')
# slice_ can now be applied to your array: arr[slice_]
```

Comment: It is important to note that if start is bigger than stop, it will return an empty array. **`arr[5:2]` is empty and no exception is raised.** That's why I was talking about security (implying validity).

Comment: You do realize that this is a perfectly valid and useful result? There is a reason for `arr[5:2]` not raising an exception.

Comment: The reason is that it is logically understandable. Slicing out of bounds return empty list. It may be invalid for GUI interface.

Comment: You do realize that f-string `f'np.s_[{b}]'` can not be used in Python 2.7? I was wondering how OP got this working! Hahahaha!

Comment: We are going off at a tangent, aren't we? ;-)

Comment: It is "go off on a tangent". However, I do not know what in particular you do not understand in my statement: **arr[5:2] is empty and no exception is raised**. Your question is redundant: `You do realize that this is a perfectly valid and useful result?` I am out! Have a nice day!

Comment: Oxford begs to [differ](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tangent) _"2 A completely different line of thought or action.
‘Loretta's mind went off at a tangent’"_

Comment: Both are valid. I am sleeping. Good night! It is 03:28 AM in Tirana, Albania.

Comment: @PaulPanzer is there an alternative to the use of `eval`? Since you said that in this case it's suitable to use it, I was wondering if there's another way to achieve the result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this i think it works, assuming that you will get min and max in your string.

```
import re
a = "2:4"
min = int(min(re.findall(r'(\d)',a)))
max = int(max(re.findall(r'(\d)',a)))
print arr[min:max]
```

Comment: This would only work for use case a, not b (slicing with another array)

Comment: If these two are your only inputs, then you should have a logic in place to identify whether it is array or slicing type. Then you can add a if else condition to process your data. For array type, the same code will work, but just increment your max value by one