# Using string in array slicing in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, slice

How can a string be used to get the relevant part of NumPy array?

```
data = np.random.random([120,120,120])
string1 = ('1:10','20:30')
data[ 1:10,20:30]
data[string1]
```

I'm getting this error :

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy slicing from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616821/numpy-slicing-from-variable)

Comment: Related: [Using string as array indices in NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351711/using-string-as-array-indices-in-numpy-python) and [Using a string to define Numpy array slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089907/using-a-string-to-define-numpy-array-slice)

Answer (score 2):

If you are trust the source of strings then you can use `eval`:

`eval('data[%s]' % ','.join(string1))`

Comment: instead of `%s` may use f string as `eval(f'data[{",".join(string1)}]')` or format method as `eval('data[{}]'.format(",".join(string1)))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this with a string. However, you can convert the strings to ints.

I am not really a pro with regular expression, but in this test case

```
import re
res = re.search("([^:]+):([^:]+)",string1[0]) 
data[int(res[1]):int(res[2])]
```

worked.

Comment: Why use regex if you can just split by `:`? e.g. `list(map(int,"29:32".split(":")))`